# Iterate over rows and expand pandas dataframe

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with a column containing values or lists of values (of unequal length). I want to 'expand' the rows, so each value in the list becomes single value in column. An example says it all:

```
dfIn = pd.DataFrame({u'name': ['Tom', 'Jim', 'Claus'],
 u'location': ['Amsterdam', ['Berlin','Paris'], ['Antwerp','Barcelona','Pisa'] ]})

    location     name
0   Amsterdam   Tom
1   [Berlin, Paris] Jim
2   [Antwerp, Barcelona, Pisa]  Claus
```

I want to turn into:

```
dfOut = pd.DataFrame({u'name': ['Tom', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Claus','Claus','Claus'],
u'location': ['Amsterdam', 'Berlin','Paris', 'Antwerp','Barcelona','Pisa']})

    location     name
0   Amsterdam   Tom
1   Berlin   Jim
2   Paris   Jim
3   Antwerp Claus
4   Barcelona   Claus
5   Pisa    Claus
```

I first tried using apply but it's not possible to return multiple Series as far as I know. iterrows seems to be the trick. But the code below gives me an empty dataframe...

```
def duplicator(series):
    if type(series['location']) == list:
        for location in series['location']:
            subSeries = series
            subSeries['location'] = location
            dfOut.append(subSeries)
    else:
        dfOut.append(series)

for index, row in dfIn.iterrows():
    duplicator(row)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you return a series whose `index` is a list of locations, then `dfIn.apply` will collate those series into a table:

```
import pandas as pd
dfIn = pd.DataFrame({u'name': ['Tom', 'Jim', 'Claus'],
                     u'location': ['Amsterdam', ['Berlin','Paris'],
                                   ['Antwerp','Barcelona','Pisa'] ]})

def expand(row):
    locations = row['location'] if isinstance(row['location'], list) else [row['location']]
    s = pd.Series(row['name'], index=list(set(locations)))
    return s

In [156]: dfIn.apply(expand, axis=1)
Out[156]: 
  Amsterdam Antwerp Barcelona Berlin Paris   Pisa
0       Tom     NaN       NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
1       NaN     NaN       NaN    Jim   Jim    NaN
2       NaN   Claus     Claus    NaN   NaN  Claus
```

You can then stack this DataFrame to obtain:

```
In [157]: dfIn.apply(expand, axis=1).stack()
Out[157]: 
0  Amsterdam      Tom
1  Berlin         Jim
   Paris          Jim
2  Antwerp      Claus
   Barcelona    Claus
   Pisa         Claus
dtype: object
```

This is a Series, while you want a DataFrame. A little massaging with `reset_index` gives you the desired result:

```
dfOut = dfIn.apply(expand, axis=1).stack()
dfOut = dfOut.to_frame().reset_index(level=1, drop=False)
dfOut.columns = ['location', 'name']
dfOut.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(dfOut)
```

yields

```
    location   name
0  Amsterdam    Tom
1     Berlin    Jim
2      Paris    Jim
3  Amsterdam  Claus
4    Antwerp  Claus
5  Barcelona  Claus
```

Comment: i'm getting an error probably because of strange data (can this be caused by emtpy values in some of the lists?): InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: This might happen if one of your location lists contains duplicate items. How do you want duplicate locations (for the same person) handled?

Comment: duplicate values should be 'merged' (e.g. only 1 should be kept in the result), empty values should be ignored.

Comment: I've changed `index=locations` to `index=list(set(locations))`. This will remove duplicates.

Answer (score 9):

Not as much interesting/fancy pandas usage, but this works:

```
import numpy as np
dfIn.loc[:, 'location'] = dfIn.location.apply(np.atleast_1d)
all_locations = np.hstack(dfIn.location)
all_names = np.hstack([[n]*len(l) for n, l in dfIn[['name', 'location']].values])
dfOut = pd.DataFrame({'location':all_locations, 'name':all_names})
```

It's about 40x faster than the apply/stack/reindex approach. As far as I can tell, that ratio holds at pretty much all dataframe sizes (didn't test how it scales with the size of the lists in each row). If you can guarantee that all `location` entries are already iterables, you can remove the `atleast_1d` call, which gives about another 20% speedup.

Comment: This solution is more elegant .

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd


dfIn = pd.DataFrame({
    u'name': ['Tom', 'Jim', 'Claus'],
    u'location': ['Amsterdam', ['Berlin','Paris'], ['Antwerp','Barcelona','Pisa'] ],
})

print(dfIn.explode('location'))

>>>
    name   location
0    Tom  Amsterdam
1    Jim     Berlin
1    Jim      Paris
2  Claus    Antwerp
2  Claus  Barcelona
2  Claus       Pisa
```