# Adding list of values to rows, turning the dataframe into long format afterwards

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the index is a genome position and the values are p-values:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict

data = """Pos   MedialIIvsD  LateralIIvsD  MedialP02IIvsD  MedialP09IIvsD
chr1_-_12200      0.557431      0.066554        0.738343        0.029935
chr1_-_12600      0.737887      0.069167        0.829568        0.409495
chr1_-_48400      0.349833      0.600912        0.964103        0.765195
chr1_-_172800     0.729035      0.035198        0.866111        0.385711"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', index_col=False, 
                 header=False)
```

In addition I have a dict that maps different genome positions to genes:

```
pos_to_gene = defaultdict(list, {"chr1_-_12200": ["GENE1"],
                                 "chr1_-_12600": ["GENE1", "GENE2"],
                                 "chr1_-_172800": ["GENE3"]})
```

What I want to achieve is adding `Gene` as a column in this dataframe. This is not straightforward to me, since there can be several genes in one genomic position:

```
pd.Series(df.index.values).apply(lambda pos: pos_to_gene[pos])
0           [GENE1]
1    [GENE1, GENE2]
2                []
3           [GENE3]
dtype: object
```

How do I achieve an output dataframe in the long format like this?

```
Gene   Pos   MedialIIvsD  LateralIIvsD  MedialP02IIvsD  MedialP09IIvsD
GENE1  chr1_-_12200      0.557431      0.066554        0.738343        0.029935
GENE1  chr1_-_12600      0.737887      0.069167        0.829568        0.409495
GENE2  chr1_-_12600      0.737887      0.069167        0.829568        0.409495
NaN    chr1_-_48400      0.349833      0.600912        0.964103        0.765195
GENE3  chr1_-_172800     0.729035      0.035198        0.866111        0.385711
```

Comment: I desperately need a better title. Would appreciate an edit.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068021/iterate-over-rows-and-expand-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks! Will have to investigate, hope it isn't an exact duplicate.

Comment: They were 90% similar, but a few more lines were needed in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trick here to use pd.Series(1, index=...) and let pandas align:

```
In [11]: s = df["Pos"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, pos_to_gene[x])).stack(0)

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0  GENE1    1
1  GENE1    1
   GENE2    1
3  GENE3    1
dtype: float64
```

You can reset the index and then simply join:

```
In [13]: s.index.names = [None, "Gene"]

In [14]: gene = s.reset_index("Gene")[["Gene"]]

In [15]: gene
Out[15]:
    Gene
0  GENE1
1  GENE1
1  GENE2
3  GENE3

In [16]: gene.join(df)
Out[16]:
    Gene            Pos  MedialIIvsD  LateralIIvsD  MedialP02IIvsD  MedialP09IIvsD
0  GENE1   chr1_-_12200     0.557431      0.066554        0.738343        0.029935
1  GENE1   chr1_-_12600     0.737887      0.069167        0.829568        0.409495
1  GENE2   chr1_-_12600     0.737887      0.069167        0.829568        0.409495
3  GENE3  chr1_-_172800     0.729035      0.035198        0.866111        0.385711
```

If you want to include the NaN row (which isn't in your answer), then outer join:

```
In [17]: gene.join(df, how="outer")
Out[17]:
    Gene            Pos  MedialIIvsD  LateralIIvsD  MedialP02IIvsD  MedialP09IIvsD
0  GENE1   chr1_-_12200     0.557431      0.066554        0.738343        0.029935
1  GENE1   chr1_-_12600     0.737887      0.069167        0.829568        0.409495
1  GENE2   chr1_-_12600     0.737887      0.069167        0.829568        0.409495
2    NaN   chr1_-_48400     0.349833      0.600912        0.964103        0.765195
3  GENE3  chr1_-_172800     0.729035      0.035198        0.866111        0.385711
```

---

As an alternative, you can create `gene` in pure python (rather than using apply):

```
inds, gens = [], []
for i, p in df["Pos"].iteritems():
    for g in pos_to_gene[p]:
        inds.append(i)
        gens.append(g)
gene = pd.Series(gens, inds)
```

Comment: Note: It may also help to use a Categorical for the Pos column, there *may* be a way to save some work if there are many repeats...

Comment: Thanks, my version was insanely slow. Will report how this worked.

Comment: There are no repeats, but will remember for another time. Thanks for your git book btw.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat oooh, you're the reader! :p I have to post some recent edits, thanks for reminding me!!

Comment: @ You should try to add it to goodreads.com so people can spread the gospel. Would give a finished version at least 4/5. And making the draft version open like (http://www.braveclojure.com/) might be a great way to get loads of good feedback/word of mouth.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat the next edit should be good, will include some real life git horror stories (and how they could've been avoided)... will definitely look into goodreads and braveclojure, thanks!  Hope performance is works for you!

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Note: in your edit, this creates a different Series (the index is now 0123 whereas in the original it's 0113), so join will give a different result. ?? (Is that the slow part of the operation?)

Comment: I bungled the edit. I'm working on creating a `Pos to Gene df`` right now which will correct this. Feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: I thought the pd.Series trick would be pretty fast, though it is space inefficient depending on how many genes there are (pandas aligning is fast). I can post an alternative python implementation, which is a little hairier...

Comment: I added a quick version that works for me now. Feel free to edit it however you like, it is your answer after all. I should have mentioned that my dataset is abolutely massive, and that most rows are not going to have genes (i.e. will become removed).

Comment: @TheUnfunCat edited with how I would've done it. Not clear if one is obviously any faster... I think this is a YMMV / %timeit and see.

Answer (score 0):

Applying what I learnt in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068021/iterate-over-rows-and-expand-pandas-dataframe):

```
df.insert(0, "Gene", df.Pos.apply(lambda pos: pos_to_gene[pos]))

def expand(row):
    genes = row['Gene']
    s = pd.Series(row['Pos'], index=list(set(genes)))
    return s

sdf = df.apply(expand, axis=1).stack()
```

returns

```
0  GENE1     chr1_-_12200
1  GENE1     chr1_-_12600
   GENE2     chr1_-_12600
3  GENE3    chr1_-_172800
dtype: object
```

which is pretty close; all that is missing is the rest of the data.

Now all that remains is merging the stacked dataframe (`sdf`) and the original (`df`).

```
sdf = sdf.to_frame().reset_index(level=1, drop=False)
sdf.columns = ["Gene", "Pos"]
pd.merge(sdf, df, left_on = 'Pos', right_on = 'Pos')
```

That was it!

```
    Gene            Pos  MedialIIvsD  LateralIIvsD  MedialP02IIvsD  \
0  GENE1   chr1_-_12200     0.557431      0.066554        0.738343
1  GENE1   chr1_-_12600     0.737887      0.069167        0.829568
2  GENE2   chr1_-_12600     0.737887      0.069167        0.829568
3  GENE3  chr1_-_172800     0.729035      0.035198        0.866111

   MedialP09IIvsD
0        0.029935
1        0.409495
2        0.409495
3        0.385711
```

Perhaps there are cleverer ways of doing this.